# How to set the minimum and maximum number of digit allowed in a regex expression for telephone number

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Regex expression for java application:

```
[\+0-9]+([\s0-9]+)?
```

How to restrict the above expression of telephone number to a minimum of 4 digits and maximum of 7 digits? I thought it would be something like adding this {4,7} to the expression but it is not working.

Any advice please?

Basically my telephone number can either start with a + sign followed with numbers(+004...) or  with numbers only(004...) and can also contain white spaces in between any digits(0 0 4...).

Comment: Take 10mn to read about [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: @HamZa. He does know about repetition. Just is unable to apply it properly in his case. Still a tutorial is worth reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
[+]?(?:[0-9]\s*){4,7}
```

Explanation:

```
[+]?           // Optional + sign
(?:[0-9]\s*)   // A single digit followed by 0 or more whitespaces
{4,7}          // 4 to 7 repetition of previous pattern
```

Sample tests:

```
String regex = "[+]?(?:[0-9]\\s*){4,7}";

System.out.println("0045234".matches(regex));       // true
System.out.println("+004 5234".matches(regex));      // true
System.out.println("+00 452 34".matches(regex));    // true
System.out.println("0 0 4 5 2 3 4".matches(regex)); // true
System.out.println("004523434534".matches(regex));  // false
System.out.println("004".matches(regex));           // false
```

Answer (score 2):

`"\\+?(\\d ?){3,6}\\d"` is supposed to match an optional + sign followed with 4-7 numbers and optional white spaces in between digits.

Answer (score 0):

Similar structure as above, but with: `:? taken off` (not sure why is it there?)

```
[+]?([0-9]\s*){4,7}
```